# what are the difference between "consumer" and "client" in oAuth?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm currently learning using dotNetOpenAuth 2.0 trying to create my own authorization server and resource server.

I got a little bit confused by the definition of "Consumer" and "Client" in its example codes - there are two projects, one called "OAuthClient" under OAuth2 folder, and one called "OAuthConsumer" under web folder.

As far as I can see, both are web applications and both functions the same... the only difference I can feel is probably it is called "Client" in OAuth 2.0 but called "Consumer" in OAuth 1.0?

I'm not sure whether my wild guess is correct, but if it is correct why they change the name? Are there any fundamental changes that caused the founder changing the names?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just lingo difference between OAuth1(Consumer) and OAuth2(Client).

Also OAuth2 samples include 2 "client" sample one is named "OAuthClient" which is a sample of a web client while "OAuthConsumerWPF" is a sample of a windows(wpf) application that act as client as well.

Comment: thanks for that! a second opinion always builds my confidence.  :) cheers.

Comment: It would be 'just' a lingo difference if there were any documentation.  However, as there is zilch of any use, it's actually one of a long list of impediments to using dotnetopenauth, which is a pity